# Row Level Security for Groups in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, row-level-security

How can I create groups in Amazon Quicksight to create a dashboard with row level security? In this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/managing-users-enterprise.html it says that you can go to  ***Manage QuickSight > Manage Users > Manage Groups***. However there is no Manage Group option for me, even though I already have an enterprise account.

Where can I go to create the groups with the users and then use a *[groupname, column]* table to filter a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what it says in the docs, I also cannot find the **Manage Groups** button. However there is an alternative using CLI according to the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/managing-users.html#creating-quicksight-groups

Says there:

> You can create user groups inside Amazon QuickSight so you don't have
> to manage users individually. For example, you can create groups for
> specific dashboards so you can manage security.
>
> Before you begin, you need to have the AWS CLI installed. For more
> information, see Installing the AWS CLI in the AWS CLI User Guide

There is no mention of creating group through Quicksight console there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a csv file and upload it to quicksight as a dataset.

Then apply row level security on that dataset, using the csv file with the rules.

Username as first column = the Quicksight account such as email
group as second column = A column that will match row by row your dataset filtering out rows that the rules do not apply.

For example your dataset will also have a column name group with values like A,B,C,D in the rows. Then in your rules csv, you place per user which rows he can see. A for just 1 group or A,C,E,F for multiple

Answer (score 0):

Quicksight is slowly adding more and more features to the UI. I heard them describe it as "We built a car with an amazing engine but forgot to add seats".

For anyone who finds this, they've now added the manage groups button.

For more updates see: https://community.amazonquicksight.com/c/announcements/12/none

Comment: If you have an official reference to support your information (tracker, "what's new", etc.) that would be a great addition to your answer